# Joining two text values to form hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm prefacing this with the fact that coding is most definitely not my strong suit.

I'm currently trying to join two pieces of text to form a link sitting behind an image. The first piece of text is defined `(https://www.example.mystore.com/customers/)` with the second part being from a datatable `(<span id="customcontent752">[Link ID]</span>)`. Question is - how do I get both of these pieces of information to join to form 
`https://www.example.mystore.com/customers/[Link ID]`? I figure it's something simple I can drop into the source code, but can't for the life of me work it out.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Did you take a look at the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstPiece = "https://www.example.mystore.com/customers/";
var secondPiece = $("#customcontent752").text().trim();
var result = firstPiece + secondPiece;  //"https://www.example.mystore.com/customers/[Link ID]"
```

Comment: So where would I place that in respect to the following code?
<p><a id="customcontent752" href="https://example.mystore.com/customers/"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="../data/files/35/image.jpg" alt="" width="58" height="56" /></a></p>

This is obviously just the link behind the image, just wondering how to use the code you've provided in respect to the above. 

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: the output you wrote is what I want - let's say the value is 123456 for link ID for a specific session - i want the script to be able to create https://example.mystore.com/customers/123456. hope this makes sense...

Comment: within the <script> tag. Can you paste your HTML part?

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat :

```
var x = "https://www.example.mystore.com/customers/"
var y ="[link ID]"
var result = x.concat(y)
```

Comment: `x` is a string but you're using concat which is an `array` prototype method

Comment: @Shaffanhoon: in javascript we can concat strings. :) I added a link for more informations.

Comment: @Shaffanhoon string is in fact and array of chars

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `+` operator if both are strings.

i.e

"https://www.example.mystore.com/customers/" + link_id

should get you what you want.

Comment: So here's what i've got for just a basic link behind the image:
So where would I place that in respect to the following code? <p><a id="customcontent752" href="example.mystore.com/customers/"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="../data/files/35/image.jpg" alt="" width="58" height="56" /></a></p>

how would I pop this into the above?